# How do I put more precision in my imported data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to improve the precision by 10 digits for the columns marked in red (Image 1), I tried `pd.set_options ('display.precision', 10)`, but it didn't work. Any ideas? the only line of code I have used is to import data from excel: `df = pd.read_excel ('')`

[image: Image 1]

Comment: I don't think this limited your data precision, that's just how it's printed to screen

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. The data in excel has 10 digits (the longest) and when passed to Python they appear as exponents. I try to import the data as it is, with all its digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your numbers are actually really big integers, so pandas converts them to 'float' as opposed to integer when they get imported. (they don't fit in standard `int64` data type).

Precision applies to decimals.  i.e. if you have something like 0.234566 etc how many decimals to show.  But in your case it's not decimals you looking for, but how many relevant digits to display, before cutting off to scientific notation.

Since it's a float data type, you have to control float format, i.e. **`pd.options.display.float_format`**

To keep scientific notation, but limit digits to 10,
set display options to this:
`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.10e}'.format`

And it will display 10 digits after decimal point before `e`.  You can change 10 to any other digit.

To understand how scientific notation works in python, try this:

`print("{:.2e}".format(12345678))`

Basically it will format 12345678 limited to 2 digits and will display as `1.23e+07` (which means 1.23 * 10^7)

**If you don't want any scientific notation, and just want to display the long integer**, use this:

**`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format`**

In this case 0 means show 0 decimals, and it will show the full integer part of the number.

eg:
`print("{:.0f}".format(1234567887298739))` returns `1234567887298739`.  While `print("{:.2f}".format(1.234567887298739487))` returns `1.23`.

Caveat: If the number is too long, it will start rounding and confusing after awhile.  I think 10 digits is ok, but if it's much larger than that, python can't really handle it and it will start rounding and cutting things up...  float precision has a system limit too.

**Note**:  In all cases your underlying data stays the same.  just the formatting changes.

Answer (score 0):

By "improve precision", I assume you mean increase the number of digits that are displayed. In this case, `pd.set_option('display.precision', 10)` should give you what you want. I have an example as well.

```
import pandas as pd
c = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")
print(c)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 10)
print()
print(c)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 20)
print()
print(c)
```

This yields the following.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHpdO.png

Make note that Pandas actually does have the actual values in memory, it is just printing less digits in accordance with default settings. As an example, you can verify this by indexing your data frames.

```
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame([123.456789101112])
>>> frame
            0
0  123.456789
>>> frame[0].data[0]
123.456789101112
```